# Asp.net webservice output sort

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a web service that reads data from database and displays it to the users. Basically a user will enter a postcode, the output will be 5 restaurants near that postcode. However, I want to sort the result according to the postcode nearest to furthest. Which C# code should I use to achieve that?
Note: I used this code to calculate distance between user's postcode and given restaurants.

```
        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %> <tr> <td>

        <% Restaurant.GoogleWebService objservice = new Restaurant.GoogleWebService();%>
        <% string Postcode2 = (item.PostCode.ToString());  %>

        <% string Postcode1 =(String)(Session["Data"]);  %>

        <% string d = (objservice.GetDrivingDistanceInMiles(Postcode1, Postcode2).ToString()); %>
        <%: d %>  <%: "Miles" %>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostCode) %>
    </td>
```

Comment: Why are you doing all your programming logic inline on the .aspx page?

Comment: Add a Miles property to your item object. Loop to get the Miles driving distance in each item. Sort the Model list by the Miles and then build the <table>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your logic from your presentation.

Put this part in the controller action:

```
var objservice = new Restaurant.GoogleWebService();
var originPostCode = (String)Session["Data"];
var results = Model.Select(item => 
    new RestaurantResult {
        Location = item.Location,
        PostCode = item.PostCode,
        Distance = objservice.GetDrivingDistanceInMiles(originPostCode,
            item.Postcode.ToString()).ToString()
    }).OrderBy(item => item.Distance);
//Pass results to the View here.
```

Replace "Model" here with whatever object holds the collection of results you previously passed to the view as the view model.

Make sure to change the model type in the view to match the type of results, alternatively use dynamic. You also have to create a new class (`RestaurantResult`) to hold the result view model.

And this in the view:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %> 
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: item.Distance %>Miles
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostCode) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I've been trying your code but it's not populating my database. I created a new column Distance in my database and added your codes in the controller so that in the view it displays the result ordered by distance. However, Distance in database is Null. Don't know what went wrong?

Comment: The distance is not saved to the database by this code. You don't need to save it to the database for the code to work, since you calculate the distance on demand.

Comment: This is what I put in HomeController:

namespace Restaurant.Controllers
{ public class HomeController : Controller
{ private RestaurantEntities1 _db = new RestaurantEntities1();
public ActionResult IndexWithDistance()
{var objservice = Restaurant.GoogleWebService(); var originPostCode = (String)Session["Data"];
var results = _db.Restaurant1.Select(item => new RestaurantResult
{Distance = ob.GetDrivingDistanceInMiles(originPostCode, item.PostCode.ToString()).ToString()}).OrderBy(item => item.Distance);
return View(_db.Restaurant1.ToList());}

But it doesn't show any result after running it.

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong since it's not giving any output, I just can't figure out where!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't able to change the model type in the view successfully to match the type of results. Can you tell me how to use dynamic? Thanks.